# How to read exactly one line from InputStream (and no additional characters)

Tags: java

I am attempting to read the first line from a gzipped input stream, and treat it as a "header" which will inform how I handle reading from the rest of the data.  However, I am having difficulty reading one and only one line (even using InputStreamReader uses a buffer under the hood, and will eat into the actual content of the underlying InputStream).  Is it possible to do this in a reasonable way?

Comment: Does one line mean all the data until the new line character?

Comment: `DataInputStream.readLine()`, but it's deprecated, and with reason.

Comment: Look into the `InputStream` [mark](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#mark(int)) and [reset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#reset()) methods, then read through a `BufferedReader` and reset the input afterwards.

Comment: @Robert He will need a `BufferedInputStream` underneath for that to actually work.